# Can't install PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install PHP 7 using the ff. command:

`sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

But when I try to run `apt-cache search php7` nothing displays and also when I try to install `sudo apt-get install php7.0` it says `Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'`. Any idea why?

I've already spent several days figuring this out. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sudo  add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 has reached End of Standard Support on March 7, 2019. According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases. Repository ppa:ondrej/php doesn’t have php7.0 packages anymore for Ubuntu 14.04 according to https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150

I bet you need to upgrade to at least Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I cn\t upgrade I'm using OpenVZ 6 VPS host it's not support newer kernals