# How to install PHP7.2 on ubuntu 14

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04. I have added this apt repository successfully:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

I try to install php7.2 but getting this output:

> apt-get install php7.2 Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree... 50% Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done Note, selecting 'php7.2-phar' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-sysvsem' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-posix' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-sysvshm' for
>   regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-msgpack' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-memcached' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-gettext' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-xdebug'
>   for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-iconv' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-soap' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-exif' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-ctype' for
>   regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-sodium' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-bcmath' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-igbinary' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-sysvmsg'
>   for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-gmp' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-pdo' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-fileinfo' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-sockets'
>   for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-zip' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-memcache' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-shmop' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-imagick' for
>   regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-common' for regex 'php7.2'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.2-calendar' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-ftp' for regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php7.2-tokenizer' for
>   regex 'php7.2' Note, selecting 'php-xdebug' instead of 'php7.2-xdebug'
>   Note, selecting 'php-msgpack' instead of 'php7.2-msgpack' Note,
>   selecting 'php-imagick' instead of 'php7.2-imagick' Note, selecting
>   'php-memcache' instead of 'php7.2-memcache' Note, selecting
>   'php-memcached' instead of 'php7.2-memcached' Note, selecting
>   'php-igbinary' instead of 'php7.2-igbinary' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-calendar' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-ctype' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-exif' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-fileinfo' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-ftp' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-gettext' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-iconv' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-pdo' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-phar' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-posix' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-shmop' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-sockets' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-sysvmsg' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-sysvsem' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-sysvshm' Note, selecting
>   'php7.2-common' instead of 'php7.2-tokenizer' php-xdebug is already
>   the newest version. php-msgpack is already the newest version.
>   php-imagick is already the newest version. php-memcache is already the
>   newest version. php7.2-soap is already the newest version. php7.2-gmp
>   is already the newest version. php-memcached is already the newest
>   version. php-igbinary is already the newest version. php7.2-common is
>   already the newest version.

I even do not see PHP7.2 packages with apt search php. I successfully installed PHP7.1 before with this repository though.

Can you help please?

Comment: hmm, try check on this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106081/cant-install-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit

Comment: The author of this repo only supports Supported Ubuntu Versions, ubuntu 14.04 has reached the end of standard support from April 2019, so you either have to upgrade your Ubuntu or install PHP from source.